# Reverse things in XML using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am learning for an exam where we should be able to reverse things in XML. I am trying to reverse the order of books, or reverse the order of elements in those books.

The input XML is:

```
   <library>
    <book>
      <author>James Joyce</author> 
      <title>Ulysses</title>
      <year>1922</year>
    </book>
    <book>
      <author>Alois Jirasek</author> 
      <title>Psohlavci</title>
      <year>1910</year>
    </book>
    <book>
      <author>Tomas Hruska</author> 
      <title>Pascal pro zacatecniky</title>
      <year>1989</year>
    </book>
  </library>
```

Reversed order of books:

```
   <library>
    <book>
      <author>Tomas Hruska</author> 
      <title>Pascal pro zacatecniky</title>
      <year>1989</year>
    </book>
    <book>
      <author>Alois Jirasek</author> 
      <title>Psohlavci</title>
      <year>1910</year>
    </book>
    <book>
      <author>James Joyce</author> 
      <title>Ulysses</title>
      <year>1922</year>
    </book>
  </library>
```

Reversing order of items in books:

```
   <library>
    <book>
      <year>1922</year>
      <title>Ulysses</title>
      <author>James Joyce</author>
    </book>
    <book>
      <year>1910</year>
      <title>Psohlavci</title>
      <author>Alois Jirasek</author> 
    </book>
    <book>
      <year>1989</year>
      <title>Pascal pro zacatecniky</title>
      <author>Tomas Hruska</author> 
    </book>
  </library>
```

I've been told that it should be quite easy, so don't try anything too fancy. I am allowed to use basic loops via for-each or recursion via apply-templates and also value-of.

Comment: And your question is? Consider: if it is "just show me how", you will not have *learned* anything and probably fail your exams.

Comment: well I already found how to copy the text, how to copy it two times, but I failed to reverse it, cause I don't know where to begin. Today I just found that xslt exists. So please don't blame me, but my question is how.

Comment: I think I could reverse the items in books matching all books and than go trough all of them and first write-down year with content than title and than autor, but it appears to me that it's to complicated... And also the library and books wouldn't be even writen down if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

First type Sort:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="library">
    <library>
    <xsl:for-each select="book">
    <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </library>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Second type:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <book>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </book>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that u can first copy the whole thing and than to reverse the position. This really helped me to get into the problem.

Comment: @Dracke, you are welcome. So many samples are there in our STACKOVERFLOW site, refer those, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to **[sort](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#sorting)** the nodes by position(), descending.

Comment: what should I match for the first and for the seccond sort?

Comment: You don't really need to match anything specific as such. You can use an [identity transform template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) (with added xsl:sort) to apply itself recursively on both books and their properties.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/library">
        <library>
            <xsl:for-each select="book">
                <xsl:sort select="author" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </library>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```